# Laravel custom table with API token

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-passport

I am using a custom table `customer` for login and also Laravel Passport to generate token for my Ionic mobile app. I am stuck at the login code where I need to generate token after query from my custom table.

Below are the login code... I can successfully retrieve the id from database but how to link it with the token?

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $phone = $request->input('phone');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $user = $token = array();

    try {
        $rs_login = DB::select("select a.id from customer a where a.active > 0 and a.phone = ? and a.password = ?", [$phone, $password]);
        $numrow_login = count($rs_login);

        if ($numrow_login != 1) {
            $this->error['form-message'] = 'ERR' . __LINE__ . ': Invalid phone number or password';
        } else {
            $user['id'] = $rs_login[0]->id;
        }
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        $this->error['form-message'] = 'Login service is unavailable';
    }

    if ($this->error == '') {
        $tokenResult = $user['id']->createToken('Personal Access Token'); // How to pass the $user['id'] to generate token?
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        $token->save();

        $token['access_token'] = $tokenResult->accessToken;
        $token['token_type'] = 'Bearer';
        $token['expires_at'] = Carbon::parse(
        $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString();
    }

    if ($this->error == '') {
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        $response['message'] = 'Login successful';
        $response['token'] =  $token;
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['error'] =  $this->error;
        $response['message'] = (isset($this->error['form-message'])) ? $this->error['form-message'] : 'Please check the form';
    }

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just specify a custom table in the `config/auth.php` instead of rewriting the entire logic

```php
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'token',
    'provider' => 'customer', // <--- Here
    'hash' => false,
],
```

And create the provider to use the specific table from the database

```php
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'customer',
    ],
],
```

And keep the default login behavior for passport

Hope this helps

Comment: hi thanks for feedback. I do not amend anything in the app/User.php?

Comment: You don't need to do anything else at all

Comment: Well you obviously have to tell the Model which table to use

Comment: can I see an example Model? I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
// changes to be made in this file: config/auth.php

// Create a custom model to override the User model

'providers' => [

'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\User::class,
],

//custom provider
'customProvider' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\CustomModel::class, // put custom model here
],
],

// attach your custom provider within the api guard to use with api calls
'guards' => [
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
],

'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'customProvider', // put custom provider here
],
],

// Use lik this in your api router
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {});

// I used it like this in LoginController

$user = CustomModel::where('email', $request -> email) -> first();

if(!Hash::check($request -> password, $user -> password)){
return response()->json(['message' => 'Authentication failed. Please check your 
credentials and try again!'], 401);
}

Auth::login($user);

$accessToken = Auth::user() -> createToken('authToken') -> accessToken;
```

Comment: Please add some clarifications also in your answer